# Function não funciona com variável no parâmetro

Tags: php, wordpress, funções

Olá,

Gosto muito de programação, mas comecei a programar há pouco tempo.

Recentemente decidimos fazer uma grande modificação no site da empresa na qual sou sócio.

Deu tudo certo, mas achei uma limitação no LearnPress, o plugin de gerenciamento de cursos que utilizamos. Gostaríamos de exibir os preços parcelados abaixo do valor integral de cada curso cadastrado no LearnPress.

Como não encontrei nenhum add-on ou algo pronto na internet, criei a seguinte function que calcula o preço parcelado de cada curso, com valor mínimo da parcela de R$9,00 e a adicionei ao arquivo functions.php do Wordpress.

Eu testei a function e ela funcionou perfeitamente.

function installment_price_course($nparcelas, $sale_price) {

$sale_price = (float)$sale_price;

$pparcelado = $sale_price/$nparcelas;

if ($sale_price < 9) {
    $nparcelas = 1;
    $pparcelado = $sale_price;
    echo $nparcelas.' x R$ '.number_format($pparcelado, 2, ",", ".").' sem juros';
}

else {

if ($pparcelado >=9) {
    $nparcelas = 12;
    echo $nparcelas.' x R$ '.number_format($pparcelado, 2, ",", ".").' sem juros';}

else {

for ($nparcelas = 12; $nparcelas >= 1; $nparcelas--) {
    $pparcelado = $sale_price/$nparcelas;
        if ($pparcelado >= 9) {
        break;
        }
}

```
echo $nparcelas.' x R$ '.number_format($pparcelado, 2, ",", ".").' sem juros';
```

}

}

}

No entanto, ao chamar a function com os parâmetros (12, $price) aparecem o seguinte erros:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/.../eduma-child/functions.php on line 101
1x R$
Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /home/.../eduma-child/functions.php on line 106
sem juros
```

Pensei que poderia ser que a variável $price fosse uma string. Então inseri o seguinte trecho na function para converter a string em float:

```
$sale_price = floatval($sale_price);
```

Após inserir esse trecho o erro desapareceu mas o valor parcelado mostrado é 0. O estranho é que se eu substituo o parâmetro variável por um número qualquer, ele retorna o valor parcelado corretamente.

Segue o código da página de curso.

//Template for displaying price of single course.

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit();

$user   = LP_Global::user();
$course = LP_Global::course();
$class = '';
$class .= ( $course->has_sale_price() ) ? ' has-origin' : '';
if ( $course->is_free() ) {
    $class .= ' free-course';
}

if ( ! $price = $course->get_price_html() ) {
    return;
}

```html
<div class="course-price">

    <div class="value <?php echo $class;?>">

        <?php if ( $course->has_sale_price() ) { ?>

            <span class="course-origin-price"> <?php echo $course->get_origin_price_html(); ?></span>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php echo $price; ?>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal"><?php installment_price_course (12, $price);?></span>
</div>
```

---

Atualização

Também notei que se eu defino uma variável $price2 e atrubuo um valor qualquer a ela, posso usá-la sem problemas como parâmetro da function. Ex.:

```
(installment_price_course (12, $price);
```

Além disso, a variável $price está ok e ela mostra o preço integral do curso normalmente. Testei-a com o echo $price e está ok.

---

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Será que isso que estou tentando fazer de colocar uma variável na chamada da function é incorreto?

Preciso muito solucionar este problema.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa concatenar as variáveis, funções e strings. No PHP a concatenação é feita com pontos (.).

Ex em seu primeiro bloco com erro:

```
echo $nparcelas.' x R$ '.number_format($pparcelado, 2, ",", ".").' sem juros';
```

• Repare que eu usei pontos (em alguns lugares você tinha usado virgula) pra juntar suas variáveis a strings.
• Você também estava adicionando espaços (pra dar espaço em branco) na parte de fora da string, modifiquei movendo pra dentro das aspas, como no trecho .' x R$ '.
• Recomendo (por questões semânticas, não obrigatórias) que você adicione espaços sempre que for separar parâmetros: Ex: ($pparcelado,2,",","."); para ($pparcelado, 2, ",", ".");

Comment: Seu segundo Warning, sobre o number_format é por que você está fornecendo um valor inteiro (provavelmente) quando se precisa de um float. (Ex: 9.75)

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções, Ederson. Corrigi o código no site.

A respeito do não funcionamento da function quando é usada a variável $price, você teria alguma ideia do motivo?

Comment: Sobre o segundo Warning, pode ser que seja inteiro (talvez até uma string). Mas por esse motivo que adicionei à function o trecho para fazer a conversão em float. Depois disso os erros sumiram, porem o resultado da function quando eu uso o $price no parâmetro dá zero. Quando eu uso outra variável com um valor definido por mim ou coloco um número no lugaro do $price, a function traz o resultado correto.

Comment: Você provavelmente está enviando um valor separado por virgula pra $price, quando se espera ter ponto como separador decimal, então o valor é confundido como string.
Por esse motivo é que você está tendo problemas somente através da variável e não da injeção direta do valor.

Comment: Bom dia, Ederson. Eu removi o number_format e também não deu certo. O valor do $price é mostrado com o separador decimal ".".  Será que por algum motivo essa variável não pode ser usada em uma function?